# Type definition in tsconfig.json not found until I enter triple directive ///<reference

Tags: typescript

I have this `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",

  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "types": [
    "jest",
    "gapi",
    "gapi.auth2"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "__sapper__/*",
    "public/*"
  ]
}
```

and this `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@docsndata/2webapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public",
    "validate": "svelte-check",
    "test": "jest --passWithNoTests"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^14.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^8.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^6.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "svelte-check": "^1.0.0",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3",
    "ts-jest": "~26.3.0",
    "jest": "~26.4.2",
    "@types/jest": "~26.0.13",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/gapi": "~0.0.39",
    "@types/gapi.auth2": "~0.0.52",
    "rollup-plugin-node-builtins": "~2.1.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "~2.3.3",
    "svelte-popperjs": "~1.0.13",
    "@types/uuid": "~8.3.0"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sirv-cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@docsndata/model-team": "~1.0.0",
    "@docsndata/google-api": "~1.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-globals": "~1.4.0",
    "@docsndata/google-auth": "~1.0.0",
    "@docsndata/firebase-auth": "~1.0.0",
    "googleapis": "~61.0.0",
    "firebase": "~7.23.0",
    "@docsndata/apps-headless": "~1.0.0",
    "@docsndata/axios-graphql": "~1.0.0",
    "@docsndata/lang-time": "~1.0.0",
    "mitt": "~2.1.0",
    "@docsndata/model-core": "~1.0.0",
    "@beyonk/svelte-notifications": "~3.1.0",
    "sveltestrap": "~3.9.4",
    "@docsndata/model-types": "~1.0.0",
    "@docsndata/model-docs": "~1.0.0",
    "@docsndata/ops-monitor": "~1.0.0",
    "@docsndata/apps-type-registration": "~1.0.0",
    "@docsndata/apps-form-coordination": "~1.0.0",
    "@docsndata/components-forms": "~1.0.0",
    "@docsndata/lang-util": "~1.0.0",
    "svelte-select": "~3.14.0",
    "@beyonk/svelte-calendar": "~2.2.1",
    "dayjs": "~1.9.5",
    "@docsndata/dom-util": "~1.0.0",
    "uuid": "~8.3.0",
    "@docsndata/apps-controllers": "~1.0.0"
  }
}
```

When I run a jest test, I get this error:

```
test/renderers/attachment/AttachmentsStream.spec.ts:26:1 - error TS2593: Cannot find name 'test'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha` and then add `jest` or `mocha` to the types field in your tsconfig.
```

When I add this line to the top of my test:

`/// <reference types="jest" />`

The test runs fine.

Why is this triple directive required, and the `types` declaration in `tsconfig.json` is not sufficient?

Comment: It should be sufficient. I suspect excluding node_modules in tsconfig. Does it make difference if you remove it?

Comment: When I stop excluding node_modules, I still get the same error